# How to copy text from Photoshop to text editor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a Photoshop file where I have a text layer with a very long paragraph. I would like to copy and paste the text to the editor where I write XHTML markup instead of rewriting it.

How can I do that? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> doesn't work.

I have Photoshop CS4.

Comment: In Photoshop CS4 the shortcuts work fine! Try with the right click and choose copy! However, I think that this isn't a question related to programming!!!

Answer (score 6):

Find the text layer in the layers list.  Double-click layer icon (with the "T" on it).  This will automatically select the text in the layer.  Then you can use the copy and paste functionality (Control-C to copy).

**You can only do this if the text is not rendered into pixels yet.  So as long has you haven't done this, it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have the clipboard turned on in Photoshop. Go to Edit > Preferences > General.

In the General box area make sure that "Export Clipboard" is checked.

Answer (score 3):

You should the Text tool (shortcut 'T') then photoshop will give you the hand to edit the text, making it possible to copy/cut/paste.

In case, it doesn't give you the hand, then it's probably not a text, and you won't be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First select the text layer in the layers palette.  Then Ctrl-A to select all.  Ctrl-C to copy.

Answer (score 1):

A roundabout way to accomplish this is to save the file as a pdf, then copy the text from there. To be safe, select Preserve Photoshop Editing Capabilities" in the save options.

Answer (score 1):

disable automatic selection of slices when using the first left control (black arrow)

Answer (score 1):

I have found other reason by chance when I'm searching for the same problem : 
When you copy a text with special chars it doesn't work like this example in french "spécial" , otherwise it works if it's "special".

Comment: This is a nasty gotcha to watch out for. I was trying to paste some emojis () that were on the end of a long line of text. The text editor (notepad++) displayed the emojis fine. But the text would just not paste into photoshop. Removed the emojis and everything worked.